# How to manipulate the DOM of a React webapp (with Chrome DevTools)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome DevTools to inspect a React webapp. The app has an upload button with a hidden input field. I'm attempting to make the input field visible (and iteractable) in two different ways:

1) In the Elements tab, I find the input HTML tag and click on it. In the Styles panel on the right, I can see that the element has a CSS style applied to it, which sets "display: none!important;". When I uncheck this line in the Styles panel, the style gets disabled, and the input element shows up on the page (and I can click on it to open the file chooser). So far, all this makes sense to me.

2) In the Sources tab, I create a new snippet and I programmatically change the display style of the same element:

```
form = ...
input = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
console.log(input);

computedStyle = getComputedStyle(input);
console.log(computedStyle['display']);

input.style.setProperty("display", "inline", "important")
console.log(computedStyle['display']);
```

When I run this, the console output makes sense: I confirm that I'm finding the correct element, the first time I print the display it's "none", and the second time it's "inline". However, nothing changes on the page, I don't see the input as in the other approach.

I'm still wrapping my head around React, and I suspect this is related to the fact that React can and will decide to recreate the actual DOM elements very often (so perhaps the input I'm changing is not the input I'm seeing?). But I'm not super clear, and either way, I was expecting these two approaches to have the same results. What happening here? And how can I programmatically change the hidden input to be not hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate dom (in react) by changing props and state. There is a browser extension which let's you do that in browser. For chrome is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en). There is extension for firefox as well.

Comment: I have the React Dev Tools. It lets me see the component tree and the props for the component that renders my input. But I can't edit the props, and even if I could, the style is not among the props. Either way, this doesn't answer my two questions above. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your snippet change did not induce a React refresh, thus the shadow DOM was modified but React did not see a reason to update the DOM.  Perhaps you could add a forceUpdate() in your snippet?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea... forceUpdate() is called on a Component. How can I access the component that renders my input element, programmatically from a snippet? (note that I can't change the React app itself)

Comment: Well, it's not a React problem.  I just ran the following code on a production React site, and the text changed color when I executed the snippet.

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('Title'))
.forEach(el => {
    el.style.setProperty('color', 'red', 'important');
})

Comment: You're right. I followed your example and tried to manipulate a different element on the same page: I was able to change the textContent as well as the display on an h2 element. And every time it would get re-rendered as expected. So there's something weird with the input element. I'll dig into it some more and I'll add more details to the question (or delete and ask a new one). Thanks!